# Laravel randomly connects to different database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have no idea how to google this since I mostly get tutorials about setting up multiple database connections.

At the moment, completely at random, my Laravel application gives me back an error about SQL, that the table could not be found. Laravel connects in this case to an entitely different database for some reason.

I connect in my .env and config/database.php to database**1**. Suddenly, an SQL error appears reading

> Cannot find table `database**2**`.`table` in field list.

User also gets logged out when this error occurs.

Might be of use if i include that:

- I sometimes use a custom user provider and sometimes the Laravel user provider. It depends on the subdomain. Error occurs on both configurations.
- I dynamically add other database connections to the config, but never one to "database2". Database2 is a completely different application.
- A search through the source code does not find any match with "database2"

Has anyone come across this problem? And if yes, how do I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Basically any Laravel Eloquent Model at seemingly Random will behave as if it was set with the public `$connection="database 2";` variable.

Comment: You need to debug your own code to identify where things go wrong. First try to identify the query or queries where this error occurs. Then try to identify how the MySQL connections are created for those queries.

Comment: I know exactly what you are talking about!!! It is happening to me! Same identical scenario! Did you ever figure this out???

Comment: Basically any Laravel Eloquent Model at seemingly Random will behave as if it was set with the public `$connection="database 2";` variable. What is a bit unorthodox in my setup is that I use Config::set('database...') during boot/service provider to define these connections, any change you are doing the same thing?

Comment: You mentioned subdomains with different application. I am wondering if our scenarios are even more similar. Are you including the different database connections for each laravel installation within one single shared global file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a model to use a different connection maybe?

Following the Laravel docs, this lets you use a different connection for specific models.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The connection name for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'connection-name';
}
```

Comment: I do not use models for the connections outside of the default connection. I use the DB::connection() for those. But thanks for your input!

Comment: Wouldn't have a clue then.. No problem!

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common reason is because you are setting your Configuration in a dynamic way with variables, so the Cache gets cached with the wrong information in this case the default database connection.

Or you could be setting the configuration at runtime which also makes the Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigCacheCommand.php to generate the wrong files.

Make sure your configurations are serializable. Try running the command.

`php artisan cache:config`